# Need to make different objects in the same array react differently

Tags: java

I am making a method to use on a array that has objects from 3 child classes of the same parent class. I want two of the classes to react differently, when third class does a certain action. Would I use a loop on the array with a .getClass() and a if-else-if statement as to what to do with each of the objects based off of the .getClass()?

Comment: you have just answered your own question. Yes you use a `for` and  `.getClass().getName()` this will give you class name

Comment: Better yet, why don't you search on the term "polymorphism"? This is one of the main foundations of oop and will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

While that would theoretically work, using `if-else-if` switches based on class's type is often considered a *code smell*.

There isn't a lot of extra info you give as to what sort of behavior and reaction you're looking for but as *first* step consider this: Can the "reaction" you want to get from the classes reasonably be considered to be a *method* of the class, and could it be a method of the parent class that the child classes override as needed?

(Think of the classical example with a class `Animal` and a method `makeSound()` and then a class `Dog` that overrides it to output `Bark!` and a class `Cat` that overrides it to output `Meow!`)

You might check here for a few ideas: https://refactoring.guru/smells/switch-statements

or provide extra info so we can figure out a good refactoring to avoid the switch block.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have a room object that holds objects of the 3 child classes. One of the classes can make the room clean or dirty, one of the other 2 classes react to the changing state. One of prefer it clean, while the other prefers it dirty. When the first class changes the room state the, other two classes either gain or lose respect.

Comment: Okay that sounds like these three classes should be able to contain all that behavior in themselves.

The room class would provide methods to query the state (e.g. `room.isClean()`) and methods to interact with the state `room.makeDirty()` and `room.cleanUp()` for example.